# center horizontally a clickable image inside a div

Tags: html, css

How do we center horizontally inside a div an image that we want to be clickable?

HTML:

```
<div class="logo-wrap">
    <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" width="262" height="53" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.logo-wrap{
    text-align: center;
}
img.logo {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I need to put the "a" tag somewhere and give it a proper CSS. Any idea?

Comment: Wrap the `a` around the image and give that a class of logo?

Comment: is there any relation between ***centering*** and ***clickable*** here? that does not make much sense.

Comment: Really? Just use the text-align:center; for the contents of the logo-wrap. If the content is inline-type it will be in the center.

Comment: In this case, the `img` and `a` tags are inline elements, so they should be centered horizontally because of `text-align: center` in the contining block.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could have figured this out

Comment: In the moment that I wrap the image or the div with an "a" tag, it is not center anymore. ---> found it! there was an extra float left associated to all the "a" tags!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal preference is to manage it all with css providing more control.

### DEMO

**HTML**

```
<div class="logo-wrap">
    <a class="logo"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.logo-wrap{
    text-align: center;
}
.logo {
    background:#68c url('img/logo.png') no-repeat center center;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:53px;
    width:262px;
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, just add an Anchor-Tag around it:

```
<div class="logo-wrap">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" width="262" height="53" />
    </a>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NoahWetjen/mLtc9/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="logo-wrap">
   <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="img/logo.png" width="262" height="53"   /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div class="logo-wrap">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

css

```
.logo-wrap{
     width:100%;
}
.logo{
    width:50%;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
img.logo {
    vertical-align: middle
}
```